# to generate/design a json Object from a set of table data

Tags: mysql, json

I have a task to design a pricing object for an org.
here are Some set of conditions:

1)Type of organization: `parent_org(10)`, `child_org(20)`

2)price of an item can be at store level, state level or at country level.
so item can have multiple prices at each of these levels and we can assume having a start and end date for each price.

so now i want to have a json object which satisfies these conditions.so that on seach of any item, i will get type of organization and all the prices at various levels.
sample data for the same is:

[data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFM1b.png)

for this sample data: what is the best way to design the Json Object.

In my view i have something like this:

```json
 {
    "SKU_INT": "5555",
    "Price_info": {         
        "org_type_10": {
        "price-levels": {
            
            "store": [
                {
                    "store-no": "0045",                  
                    "price": "10.90",                  
                    "start-date": "2020-01-01",
                    "end-date": "2021-01-01"                 
                },
                {
                    "store-no": "2410",                  
                    "price": "110.98",                  
                    "start-date-Date": "2020-01-01",
                    "end-date": "2021-01-01"                 
                }
            ],
          "state": [...],
          "country":[...]
          }
          },
          "org_type_20": {...}
                  
  }
  }
```

Does this approach effective .. or is there any better way to deal this situation.

Comment: This seems to be an assignment given to you. You should design this yourself and submit your original solution

Comment: The table is flat - so JSON must be flat too. Multi-level JSON makes sense when you create it from the data taken from a lot of linked tables. So normalize your DB structure firstly.

Comment: @AmirSaleem - This is a POC i am addressing as part of my course. And I would like to know a better approach as I am still learning things.

Comment: @Akina - this data is output of couple of linked tables.. but something similar is used  for jsonobject.

Comment: *this data is output of couple of linked table* If so then you have an hierarchy initially. JSON must match it. Do not try to build something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a relational database, then IMO it should have the following schema. We can still improve this, as I implemented this in less time.

### Master Tables

ORGS - Stores all Organisations

SKU_INT - Store all SKU_INT (I don't what this is)

ZONE_STORE - Stores all Zone Stores

Then you have a one to many relationship between ORGS and SKU_INT

| OrgIs | SKU_INT |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1111 |
| 10 | 3333 |
| 10 | 5555 |

One to Many relationship between SKU_INT and ZONE_STORE

| SKU_INT | ZONE_STORE |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1539 |
| 1111 | 1910 |

Each ZONE_STORE will have a pricing

| ZONE_STORE | PRICING | START_DATE | END_DATE | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1539 | 10.99 | 1/31/2021 | 2/31/9999 | COUNTRY |

Then your JSON output from the above tables will look like this

```json
{
    "organisations": [
        {
            "type": "10",
            "sku_int": [
                {
                    "id": "1111",
                    "zone_store": [
                        {
                            "id": "1593",
                            "pricing": [
                                {
                                    "price": 10.99,
                                    "start": "1/31/201",
                                    "end": "12/31/999",
                                    "type": "country"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "5555",
                    "zone_store": [
                        {
                            "id": "109",
                            "pricing": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1357",
                            "pricing": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```